# SSIS No precedence constraints in sequence container

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

I am currently working on troubleshooting an SSIS package and noticed that in the sequence container there a no precedence constraints. How can I predict what order the tasks will happen in? Currently, the package is running without failing. Can I predict the order of the tasks?[image]

Comment: Anecdotally, I've seen tasks in that situation execute in alphanumeric order of their name (what you see on your screenshot).  But this may only be accidental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those tasks will all run in parallel (up to the maximum amount of threads which I'm too lazy to look up the formula). Assuming the number of threads is under 10, there is no published algorithm that I'm aware of that will identify which tasks will get the signal to begin processing in a specified order.